# Why are those characters wrongly encoded?

Tags: windows, character-encoding

I have a question about character encoding.

I just received an e-mail that's supposed to use "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1252", but accented characters look like this:

> Votre email a bien =E9t=E9 envoy=E9 =E0 "dummy".

instead of:

> Votre email a bien été envoyé à "dummy".

Why is that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The message body is QP encoded, and either the message headers lack the information about this, `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`, or your e-mail client cannot interpret QP encoding (get a new e-mail client then).